# How to keep all hyperlinks working when exporting my workbook as pdf file?

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2016 VBA and the [Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) Method, how can I keep the hyperlinks between multiple sheets working?

The resulting pdf gets all the sheets and the hyperlinks format, but they do not work. On the other hand, the same method, when used with [Microsoft Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat), keeps hyperlinks working.

The code I use is as follows, and Sheet1 have hypelinks to Sheet2 and Sheet3:

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    "C:\tempo.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I eventually got it to work by doing this:

1) I moved my links to different cells and I **formatted the link cells as Text**.

2) I created the links I wanted to export using the [HYPERLINK()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) function on the Text-formatted fields.

That should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @swmcdonnell, but it did not worked for me. I formated the "target" cell in Sheet2 as text, and then I created the hyperlink formula inside the "origin" cell in Sheet1, both formatted as text and formatted as general. In the first case the formula became a simple text, then, not showing me the hyperlink feature. In the second case the hyperlink feature happened and worked, but only while as workbook. When I exported as pdf, the hyperlink in the pdf lost its function as before. :(

Comment: This solution does create hyperlinks but **the hyperlinks point to the original XLSX** file instead of the pages in the actual PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of 3rd party software, internal cross-reference hyperlinks in a Excel document cannot be fully preserved when exporting to PDF. **Explanation** and **semi-solutions** for partially working internal cross-reference hyperlinks **are given below**.

**Explanation:**

As [stated by Kevin on SE](https://superuser.com/a/264827/1710667), only external hyperlinks (to other files or URLs) are preserved when exporting to PDF using the `Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`. Internal document cross-reference hyperlinks are lost during the export.

As [stated by Brian on SE](https://superuser.com/a/245814/1710667), using 3rd party software such as Adobe Acrobat, it might be possible to create PDF file preserving internal cross-reference hyperlinks. However, this is not a pure-excel approach.

**Semi-solution 1 (links only work in PDF opened in web browser):**

If we want to avoid using 3rd party software, this semi-solution is available. Using this solution, internal ***hyperlinks to specific pages of the exported PDF file*** can be created. However, the internal hyperlinks ***only work when the PDF file is opened in a web browser***. Moreover, the hyperlinks only work in the PDF file, not in the Excel document.

If we want to create a hyperlink which will point to a specific page (e.g. 15) in the exported PDF file, we can use the following syntax in Excel.

```
=HYPERLINK("#page=15","displayed text")
```

The `#` operator is ussually used in Excel as a [dynamic-reference operator](https://trumpexcel.com/create-dynamic-hyperlinks-in-excel/) telling the formula to refer to cells in the same workbook. However, in this case, the entire reference (`#page=15`) is in a format supported not by the Excel, but by the web browser opening the exported PDF file.

Thus, when you open your PDF file in web browser (e.g. `file:///C:/filename.pdf`), and you click on the hyperlink, you are redirected to the page with the number given in the reference (e.g. `file:///C:/filename.pdf#page=15`)

**Semi-solution 2 (external links to online-stored copy):**

This semi-solution is more of a workaround than a solution. Using this solution, ***hyperlinks to specific pages of the exported PDF file*** can be created. However, the ***hyperlinks will open a online-stored copy of the file***.

If a file-hosting service is available, you can upload your PDF file to the service (e.g. `http://my1337hosting.com/filename.pdf`), and then create an [external hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521810/11875147) (e.g. `http://my1337hosting.com/filename.pdf#page=15`) to the online-stored version of the PDF file.